# Laravel: Passar parametros nas rotas

Tags: php, laravel, yaml

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de CMS, onde eu escolho o componente que o usuário que na sua pagina do site.

Nessa linha do codigo eu carrego os dados dos componentes, esse dados estão vindo de um arquivo `components.yaml` que traz essa configuração.

```
    <div class="list-group">
    @foreach( $components as $component)
        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action btn btn-outline-primary">{{ $component->title }} : {{ $component->component }}</a>
    @endforeach
    </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento eu quero que ao clicar em um comoponete desse eu gere essa rota: `website/{website}/pages/{page}/components/create?componente=page-simpleheader`

No caso queria saber como passo esse parametro na rotas do laravel? `?componente=page-simpleheader`, nessa rota vou carregar a view com o formulário para cadastrar esse componente na pagina.

Rotas

```
        Route::group([
        'as' => 'pages.',
        'prefix' => 'pages/{page}',
        'middleware' => 'managercontext:website_page'
    ], function() {

        Route::resource('components', 'Website\PageContentComponentsController', [
            'only' => ['show', 'create', 'store', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy']
        ]);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você vai fazer por GET basta passar os parâmetros com barra igual esse exemplo:

```
Route::get('/rota/{parametro1}/{parametro2}', 'MeuController@minhaFuncao')->name('dashboard');
```

e na função do controller ficaria assim o recebimento dos parâmetros.

```
function minhaFuncao($parametro1, $parametro2){

}
```

exemplo de rota com os parâmetros

```
localhost:8000/rota/valor1/valor2
```